# Method Updating Data Twice on Form Submission

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that is a form that I input a name and it updates a value on a field on the backend based on which input the name is. Right now I have two inputs (host and scout) and they work fine if I just fill one input. My problem is, when I fill both inputs, the name on the host input will always get updated twice while the name on the scout field will work just fine. Not sure if I was clear enough.

Here is the code for the component so far

```
<template>
  <div class="add-wave">
    <h3>Add Wave</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <form @click.prevent="addwave()" class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="host" />
            <label class="active">Host</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="scout" />
            <label class="active">Scout</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        <router-link to="/member" class="btn grey">Cancel</router-link>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db, fv } from "../data/firebaseInit";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      host: null,
      scout: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addwave() {
      this.addhost();
      db.collection("members")
        .where("name", "==", this.scout)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            doc.ref.update({
              scout: fv.increment(1),
              total: fv.increment(1)
            });
          });
        });
    },
    addhost() {
      db.collection("members")
        .where("name", "==", this.host)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            doc.ref.update({
              host: fv.increment(1),
              total: fv.increment(1)
            });
          });
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm not sure why is it updating twice only when I fill both input fields.

Comment: `<form @click.prevent="addwave()"`. Do you really want to call `addwave` whenever there's a click anywhere on the form? Was that meant to be a `submit` event?

Comment: that fixed the problem. Don't know how I didn't caught it before. Sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eye. Thank you so much